# Roman numbers on annexes

Tags: sectioning, numbering, roman-numerals

I'd like to have roman numbered annexes like this:

1 First Section

2 Second Section

3 Final Section

Bibliography

Annexes

I First Annex

II Second Annex

III Third Annex

IV Fourth Annex

I'm guessing I should do something like

```
\setcounter{section}{1}
\renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}}
\section*{Annexes}

\subsection{First Annex}
```

but how can I remove the section number and leave only the subsection number with a roman numeral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've solved it while building the MWE. Actually Latex does all the work by itself, only the command `\renewcommand\thesubsection{\Roman{subsection}}` is necessary.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twocolumn]{article}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\section{First Section}

\section{Second Section}

\section{Third Section}

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Annexes}
\sectionmark{Annexes}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\Roman{subsection}}
\section*{Annexes}

\subsection{First Annex}

\subsection{Second Annex}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The structure of the solution you propose differs from the structure of the question you posed. Specifically, I thought you wanted the annexes to have the same depth as have the sections. Thus, something like `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Annexes} \sectionmark{Annexes} \setcounter{section}{0} \renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}} \section*{Annexes}
\section{First Annex} \section{Second Annex}` may answer your question more closely.

Comment: Thanks @Mico, the section is ok being Annexes and each annex being a subsection. The last sentence of the question gives the hint. I mistakenly though that the section number 0 would be kept and give 0.I but it didn't.

Comment: The size option is called `10pt`, without spaces; the fact that also `10 pt` works is just by chance.

Comment: @egreg oops, noted.